# UnBoundLocalError in Python while printing global variable

Tags: python

Why is this code giving 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num1' referenced before assignment' error?

```
num1=50
def func():
   print(num1)
   num1=100
func()
```

Comment: Because you are redefining `num1` _**inside**_ of `func()`, Python considers `num1` local to `func()`. So when you attempt to print the _global_ `num1`, Python only finds the _local_ `num1` and raises an error because it sees it has not been defined yet.

Comment: But it should take the global value of num1 right?

Comment: No, if you assign to a variable anywhere in a function, the compiler marks it as local, unless you use the `global` directive.

Comment: ok thank you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another gotcha! of python. This is because of *hoisting* and *variable shadowing*. If you have a local and global variable with the same name in a particular scope, the local variable will shadow the global one. Furthermore, declarations are *hoisted* to the top of their scope.

So your original code will look something like this:

```
num1=50
def func():
   num1 = ... # no value assigned
   print(num1)
   num1=100
func()
```

Now, if you try to print `num1` without having assigned any value to it, it throws `UnboundLocalError` since you have not *bound* any value to the variable at the time you are trying to dereference it.

To fix this, you need to add the `global` keyword to signify that `num1` is a global variable and not local.

```
num1=50
def func():
   global num1
   print(num1)
   num1=100
func()
```

Comment: Can you explain hoisting?

Comment: @Saurav.Kumar Like I said, declarations are moved to the top of their enclosing scope.