# Python accessing global module fails in function with import

Tags: python

The following program throws `UnboundLocalError` but I don't understand why.
It's a very condensed version of a nasty bug found in one of my scripts.

EDIT: I don't accept the explanation of "variable hoisting". I don't think this actually happens in Python. If the function namespace is printed, it shows that `pickle` does not exist locally. Going by the LEGB lookup rules, Python should find the `pickle` name in the global namespace.

Sometimes it takes a while to frame the question. I guess the real question is *why*. I understand what is happening, but why does Python do this? Why does Python break its own LEGB lookup rules?

```
import pickle

def func(number):
    print("Global variables=%s" % repr(globals()))
    print("Local namespace=%s" % repr(dir()))
    dir(pickle) # This line will fail
    import pickle   # This line is the cause of the failure.
    return number

func(5)
```

Program output:

```
Global variables={'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'c:\\python27\\globaltext.py', '__package__': None, 'func': <function func at 0x02320E70>, '__name__': '__main__', 'pickle': <module 'pickle' from 'C:\Python27\lib\pickle.pyc'>, '__doc__': None}
Local namespace=['number']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    func(5)
  File "test.py", line 4, in func
    dir(pickle) # This line will fail
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pickle' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You should make this a [mcve] though. Most of the code (like the `number` stuff) isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnBoundLocalError in Python while printing global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645109/unboundlocalerror-in-python-while-printing-global-variable)

Comment: I think this is the same as the linked issue: you're shadowing the global `pickle` with your local `pickle`, and the local declaration is hoisted to the top of the function.

Comment: I don't think Python "hoists" variables. If I add a `print(dir())` statement at the start of the function, it shows the local namespace only contains `number` and there is no `pickle`. Going by the LEGB look-up rules, when it doesn't find `pickle` it should look in the global namespace.

Comment: Maybe hoisting is kind of a red herring. The point is that because you assign to `pickle` *somewhere* inside the function, python considers every reference to it in the function as a local reference.

Answer (score 0):

The `import pickle` in the function causes the name `pickle` to be marked as a local. The code then fails at runtime when it attempts to access a local that has not yet had a value assigned.

The top level `import pickle` isn't required for this to happen. This is not even specific to `import`. The following has the same issue:

```
def func():
    x # This line will fail
    x = 1  # This line is the cause of the failure.

func()
```

The error is `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` without the assignment to mark the name as a local the error is `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined`.

Comment: That explains what is happening, but not why. Why doesn't Python apply LEGB lookup rules just because the name is also used locally later on? In an interpreted language I wouldn't expect this to happen. I guess that's my real question.

Answer (score 0):

It is **shadowing** of one variable to another variable. Variable declared within a function can overshadow another variable declared outside of it. You can use another word for it **SCOPE**

Here you can find explanation and examples as well [LINK](http://www.oznetnerd.com/python-shadowing/).

Similar question on [stack1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645109/unboundlocalerror-in-python-while-printing-global-variable) , [stack2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125172/how-bad-is-shadowing-names-defined-in-outer-scopes)

Comment: In this case, I expect shadowing to work, but it's not. Those other explanations talk about *hoisting*, but printing the local namespace shows that hoisting is not happening. This question has been asked before but I don't think it has been answered correctly.

Comment: In your case it is shadowing. "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pickle' referenced before assignment", you are importing pickle after calling pickle.